# Полное резервное копирование диска с несколькими установленными системами на USB

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, резервное-копирование, kali-linux

В общем на диске стоит Windows и рядом Linux. Нужно так скопировать диск, чтобы в итоге получилась флешка для автоматической установки на пустую систему, в общем загрузочная флешка нужна.

Comment: Acronis?   Не, не пройдет?

Comment: Нет. Рассматриваем только опенсорсные методы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloneZilla так умеет. В два этапа: сначала создаём образ системы, а потом запаковываем его в самодостаточный iso.

[image: Режим создания загрузочного диска]

Comment: этот вариант мне знаком , как бы это же провернуть стандартными средствами линукс

Comment: А что такое "стандартное средство"? kernel+busybox?

Comment: Это средства которые устанавливаются по умолчанию в большинстве дистрибутивов

Comment: Так тебе же весь диск надо копировать. Зачем `устанавливаются`? Если тебе важно `по умолчанию в большинстве дистрибутивов ` - то используй `dd+xz`, но это - быдлометод.

Comment: Вот именно DD. как бы записать самоустанавливающийся образ на флешку ? Используя стандартные средства линукс

Comment: Пишешь образ через dd, потом закидываешь `tinycore` или `alpine` на флэшку каким-нить `rufus`. Но ещё раз: это - быдлометод уровня "я у мамы хакир".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91174/discussion-between-gybernaty-and-don-rumata).